# Is there a way to add a delay on a hover efect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I would like to accomplish is that when the image changes after the hover it stays like that for a few seconds, and then it returns to the original image.
What I would like to know is if there's a way to add that kind of delay. I have attached my code below.

```
<html>

<body>

<img src='http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg'
     width='142' height='162'
     onmouseover="this.src='http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg';"
     onmouseout="this.src=http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg';" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look into CSS transitions and animations. You don't want to use onmouse events but CSS :hover with a transition on the background property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS transitions with the `transition-delay` property.

```css
.classname {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

.classname:hover {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  width: 142px;
  height: 162px;
  background-image: url('http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition-property: background-image;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

.image:hover {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background-image: url('http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg')
}
```

```html
<div class="classname"></div>

<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: If I had 50 different images with 50 different background changes is it a good idea to use this method?

Comment: @sfbarts hard to say. It really depends on how you intend to set up your code, how you maintain it and what you want to achieve. I would naturally look into javascript for something like this, but there is nothing inherently wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onmouseout` event to call a JS function with `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
      this.src= "...";
 }, 5000);
```

Where 5000 is the time in milliseconds you want to delay.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use CSS transitions.

```css
.button {
   background-color: #222;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 14px 36px;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: 0.6s background-color ease
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='button'>Hover me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example to change `<img>` `src` with `onmouseover` event and wait 3's then get back to original image onmouseout

```js
//copy original img to variable
var original = $("img")[0].src;
//mouse over event
$("img").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
  //change image
  $(this)[0].src = "http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg";
});
//mouse out event
$("img").mouseout(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  //on mouse over wait 3 second and getback to original img
  setTimeout(function() {
    img.fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
    img[0].src = original;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg' width='142' height='162' />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a several ways to do this.
You can try the snippet below:

```
<div>
    <img src='http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg' width='142' height='162'/>
    <img src='http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg' width='142' height='162'/>
  </div>

div{
  width:142px; 
  height:162px;
  overflow: hidden; /*required*/
}
div img{
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  transition-delay: .5s; /*time of transition that you want*/
}
div img:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Another way is just use a background of this images and manage each one.

Full example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fixubulole/edit?html,css,output)